# replace each node of a tree with sum of all values in left side of the node without using extra integer pointer argument

Tags: c++, c, pointers, data-structures, tree

Given a binary tree, I need to change the **value in each node to sum of all the values** in the nodes **on the left side of the node**. Essentially each node should have the value equal to sum of all values of nodes visited earlier to this node in in-order traversal of the tree. Important point is this **has to be done without using integer pointer argument**. I am able to solve it with interger pointer argument to hold sum like this. Without this integer pointer variable, How do I hold sum when I visit right side of a node from its parent.

```
void modifyBST(struct node *root, int *sum) {

    if (root == NULL)  return;

    // Recur for right subtree
    modifyBSTUtil(root->left, sum);

    // Now *sum has sum of nodes in right subtree, add
    // root->data to sum and update root->data
    *sum = *sum + root->data;
    root->data = *sum;

    // Recur for left subtree
    modifyBSTUtil(root->right, sum);
}
```

**How do I modify this method such that int *sum can be removed**.
My complete program is here [click here](http://ideone.com/zc61f0)

Example tree: 
Example tree: 
inorder: 4 2 5 1 6 3 7
preorder: 1 2 4 5 3 6 7
output :  4 6 11 12 18 21 28

Comment: _'has to be done without using integer pointer argument.'_ What about using a reference then (`void modifyBST(struct node *root, int& sum)`)? Are you asking for [tag:c++] or [tag:c] actually?

Comment: reference is c++ is same like pointer in C right..so should not use reference

Comment: Then you'll have to accumulate `sum` via the return value.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ : I thought of it but when visiting right side node of a parent how to pass sum obtained upto the parent to that node using recursion? Im unable to write that logic. If I am going to add both descendents then I can write recursion to return both descendents and add at parent.

Comment: Alternatively, if you are able to provide a node visiting class, you could hold sum as a member.

Comment: Would you mind trying if [this code](http://ideone.com/RzhaTn) works for you?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: It did not work

Comment: Could you make a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please, that we can play with your actual code. And **please** decide for c or c++. Also changing the order of left/right sub tree visits could change for the right result (changed the sample).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: I have added a link to my question which has complete program

Comment: The output of the example doesn't match with your question. Also note your comments about left/right subtree traversal and parameters passed to the recursive call are inconsistent.

Comment: Try passing down the sum accumulated so far and returning the new sum.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: I fixed the comment. Otherwise program is correct. I have now changed the input tree to same as what i posted in question. you can check

Comment: @n.m. : How to do that is my question since I cant use extra argument. Note also that I dont know how to pass sum to right child from parent.

Comment: You use an integer argument, not a pointer.

Answer (score 2):

```
int modify(struct node* node,int sum)
{
     if (node == NULL)
          return 0;

     int l=modify(node->left,sum);
     int r=modify(node->right,sum+l+node->data);

     int x=node->data;

     node->data=node->data+l+sum;

     return x+l+r;

}
```

Call the function using statement:

```
modify(root,0);
```

*Full implementation : http://ideone.com/A3ezlk*

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution:

Rephrasing the question, what you really want to do is set each node's sum to the previous node's sum + the value associated with that node, i.e.

node<sub>n</sub>->sum = node<sub>n-1</sub>->sum + node<sub>n</sub>->value

Right now, you are setting node<sub>n</sub>->sum when you visit node<sub>n</sub>, but the issue you are running into is you don't have easy access to node<sub>n-1</sub>->sum without passing it as a parameter.  To work around this, I would suggest setting node<sub>n</sub>->sum when you DO have easy access to node<sub>n-1</sub>->sum, i.e. when you visit node<sub>n-1</sub>

Some C code to show what I mean

```
void modifyBST(struct node *curNode)
{
    struct node* next = treeSuccessor(curNode);
    if(next != NULL)
    {
        next->sum = curNode->sum + next->value;
        modifyBST(next);
    }
}
```

The assumption is that `curNode->sum` has been set before modifyBST is called for that node, which is valid for the first node (as its sum is just equal to its value) and inductively valid for all other nodes.

You would use this method by finding the first node (the one with value 4 in your example), if necessary setting sum equal to its value, and calling modifyBST with that node as the argument.

TreeSuccessor is a fairly well known algorithm, you can find pseudocode for it many places online if you need.

Answer (score 0):

I think below code should work just fine. I have not tested it, just checked it manually.

I hope this helps:

```
int modifyBST(struct node *root) {

    if (root == NULL)  return 0;

    root->data += modifyBSTUtil(root->left);

    return (root->data + modifyBSTUtil(root->right));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your pointer argument variable `sum` never changes, we can easily get rid of it.

```
int sum;

void modifyNode(struct node *root)
{
    if (!root) return;

    modifyNode(root->left);
    sum = root->data += sum;
    modifyNode(root->right);
}

void modifyTree(struct node *root)
{
    sum = 0, modifyNode(root);
}
```

[integrated](http://ideone.com/JMfvvQ)